# High Level Discussion: Generate synthetic sensor data using data from surrounding sensors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, geospatial, sensors

Let's assume I have readings coming from sensors. For every sensor, I have the following information:

1. all the data it reads
2. its location

Now, given an arbitrary sensor at an arbitrary location between these sensors, we want to predict the stream of data coming from this sensor. We would like to generate a synthetic stream of data, using the data coming from the other sensors and knowing their locations relative to our target sensor.

How would I go about solving such a problem? What is the "general idea" and "data-driven techniques" to handle such a problem?